# Yii 2: Using a component only in backend

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have developed a component to crop images, and now I am migrating it to Yii 2.
There are a PHP class, a JS, a CSS, and an image files.

I am in doubt whether I place these files. Is it better to create a directory at **basepath/vendor**, or to add in the respective directories (**image**, **css**, and **js**), on **backend/web** and reference them in **backend/assets/AppAsset**? Note that I will only use this component in the backoffice.

What is the conventional way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my experience is better build a component in `vendor/yourVendorName/yourModuleName`  in the form of `module` and the you can use it where do you prefer adding to `modules` section of `config/main.php` of your app

Comment: Besides this you should create a Asset class that would load whenever you need the JS and CSS files. They will automatically get copied someplace that is web accessible (in web/assets).

Comment: @MihaiP. Does the Asset class may be inside the component? Is there some reference in the documentation that I can study?

Comment: See here https://github.com/MihailDev/yii2-elfinder , this is their assets https://github.com/MihailDev/yii2-elfinder/blob/master/Assets.php it points to the css and js files that are in the package, they just register it when they need it.